# Driving two motors from one power source

Tags: motor, solar-cell

I have built a little balsa wood buggy for my daughter's teddy, the idea being to drive it with solar panels.

I can get one motor working with this set up no problem, but having problems with two (one in each driving wheel).

I have two solar panels, each of which can drive one motor fine, but I don't know how to get them to work together.

I currently have the solar panels in parallel for increased current, and the motors in series (just because I was - almost certainly wrongly - thinking of LED circuits where you want the same current through both.

In this set up though, the motors run at wildly different speeds, and in anything other than full sun one runs nicely and the other doesn't turn at all.

The teddy won't complain if the motors aren't exactly the same speed, but I do want roughly the same output from both for a given amount of light.

Before I start messing around trying all the different permutations of series/parallel, is there a "correct" way to do this? Would I be better having one panel per motor, not connected together at all?

Comment: Put the motors in parallel.

Comment: Turning the same speed typically requires either feedback control or a magnetic clutch.  You're probably better off with a single motor and a solid axle, drive with a rubber band belt.

Comment: Or get a [technic-lego differential](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/174951-new-two-piece-differential-details-comparison/). Highly recommended if I might say. [Picture](https://mybrick.com.au/images/diffpack1.jpg)

Comment: Motor impedance rising drastically with speed unlike LEDs and the largest impedance gets most of the voltage. however In parallel the kV/rpm may not be perfectly matched but at least its closer to matched impedances.

Comment: Modify it to a three-wheel buggy.

Comment: I put the motors in parallel and the buggy works fine for a toy bunny, so thanks Andyaka for the first response and Tony Stewart for the explanation - if either of you want to put that as an answer I'm happy to mark it the correct one